# secure node api: Use php sessions?

Tags: node.js, session, authentication

I am using Symfony2 in an example chat app to serve the website and to do registering and authentication stuff. Node.js as communication server and backbone.js as client provide the chat functionality.

The question is now how I could secure the node.js api (socket.io, REST).

My first thought was just to share the session in a redis db for node.js and symfony2 but this  would tie them together and I couldn't use node as standalone api (for other projects).

So my question is if there are better strategies (maybe sent the credentials with each header) so that the api and php are more decoupled.

Regards

Comment: you should read this http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/ as it "sort-of" answers your question about securing the ReST api.

Comment: Hi thank you for the link. I found several libs supporting OAuth2: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth, https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth but I didn't sort out if they are just for authorisation. The HMAC is also interesting.

Comment: Is it only possible to authenticate against 3rd party OAuth2 services or is there also the possibility to create an own OAuth2 service?

Comment: Creating an OAuth2 service isn't terribly hard, just involved. There are a couple articles out there on how to do it with your webstack of choice.